# Restler API Explorer POSTing JSON data

Tags: php, restler

I am having a problem posting JSON data to my Restler Web Service using the Restler API Explorer.

Here is an example

```
/**
 * Inserts a product
 * 
 * @param string    $product_id {@from body} The SKU for the product
 * @return a product object which contains the product
 */
function post($product_id=NULL, $request_data=NULL){

error_log(var_export($request_data,1));
}
```

When I post the following JSON string thru the explorer

{"product_id": "MOO"}

I get the following outputted in the log

```
array ('{____"product_id":_"MOO"}' => '','index_url' => 'index',)
```

Whereas if I use CURL e.g.

```
curl -X POST http://xxx.xxx.xxx/products.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"product_id": "MOO"}'
```

I get

```
array ('product_id' => 'MOO','index_url' => 'index',)
```

Which is what I would expect.

Can any spot what is wrong?

Cheers
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a bug in API Explorer that is fixed a month back

Update your explorer to the latest from https://github.com/Luracast/Restler-API-Explorer

Delete your cache and see the issue go away